# Initialise public members of a struct with a default constructor

Tags: c++11, initialization

Given a toy `struct` with a default constructor like this one:

```
struct RGB {
    unsigned char r, g, b;

    RGB() 
        :r(0), g(0), b(0) {}
};
```

How do I initialise one to a specific colour, assuming I don't have access to the source code to add my own constructor.

I don't understand fully why these don't work:

```
// OK, I can sort-of accept this one
RGB red = {255, 0, 0};

// Not shorthand for green.r=0, green.g=255, green.b=0;?
RGB green = {.r = 0, .g = 255, .b = 0};

// I seem to be missing a constructor that accepts a list?
RGB blue{0, 0, 255};
```

Is there any other C++11 way to shorten the good old-fashioned:

```
RGB yellow;
yellow.r = 255;
yellow.g = 255;
yellow.b = 0;
```

Furthermore, how could I minimally modify the `struct` declaration to support any of the above, as well as having a default initialisation method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no possibility to add default arguments to the struct's constructor, how about a helper function:

```
RGB makeRGB(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b)
{
    RGB result;
    result.r = r;
    result.g = g;
    result.b = b;
    return result;
}
```

Which can be used like so:

```
RGB red = makeRGB(255, 0, 0);
```

[Return value optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) will take care of the temporary and provide a no-overhead solution unless you are using a terrible compiler.

---

The ideal solution would be modifying the default constructor to take optional arguments:

```
struct RGB {
    unsigned char r, g, b;

    explicit RGB(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b) 
        :r(r), g(g), b(b) {}
    RGB() : RGB(0, 0, 0) {}
};
```

Which can be used like you would expect:

```
RGB red(255, 0, 0);
RGB green{0, 255, 0};
RGB blue;
blue.b = 255;
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c201513729e914b).

Comment: The "ideal solution" isn't so ideal - it defines an implicit conversion from `unsigned char` to `RGB`.

Comment: Thanks, I was probably overthinking the problem. I should submit a bug report/change request to the project that generates the problematic headers to see if they can make slightly more initialisation-friendly constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
struct color
{
color(std::initializer_list<float> list) = delete;
float r, g, b;
};
```

1. `color c = {1,2,3}` and `color c {1,2,3}` are the same.
2. syntax like `color c = {.r = 0, .g = 255, .b = 0};` is specific to C programming language, not C++.
3. `color c = {1,2,3};` is perfectly fine in C++11. It is called [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). And it does even override explicit constructor from `initializer_list`. Link describes how to explicitly delete it.
4. Constructor from `initializer_list` can be explicitly called by `color c({1,2,3})`